# Deploying over an existing Firebase Function without deleting it first fails silently or leads to "Internal" error when called

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Our Firebase Functions have been working fine. However, we noticed that recently when we deploy a new version of a function over an existing one, e.g. "firebase deploy --only functions:PurchaseShopItem", the deploy will report success. But the PurchaseShopItem function will simply be the old version. We can even look at the source code and see that it's still the old version.

The only work around is to manually delete the function either from the CLI or from Firebase Functions console.

Related problem: When bulk deploying (for example, "firebase deploy --only functions") some of our functions get stuck in a state where they are present in the Functions Console, but trying to call them leads to an immediate "internal" error return code to the client. No log appears in the Firebase Functions Logs. The fix is the same: If we delete the function first then redeploy, it starts working.

Even deleting a function by removing it from index.js and redeploying doesn't seem to work (the existing function just fails with "internal" and no more information.) Only deleting the function from Console or explicitly from CLI seems to work to replace it.

Has anyone seen this where you must manually delete a function in Firebase Functions Console before you can deploy over it? Are there any work arounds? Are we doing something wrong?

Comment: To add more info: We've noticed that certain functions fail to deploy over their old versions. This problem happens to the same functions across multiple copies of our firebase functions (we have different test environments that often run the same copies of functions.) So, when we go to revise a function, we deploy it, it fails to deploy over, we delete the existing one manually, then redeploy and it works. And this same thing happens on the same function across different copies of the project. So, it appears to have something to do with the contents of the function bundle.

Comment: I have the same issue and I believe that if the code has some errors (like Javascript errors) the deploy somehow fails without telling you...

Answer (score 0):

It can take some time for a function to fully deploy after the CLI finishes.  That's expected, and the total time can vary.  You're not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this heads up. Do you have a ballpark of how long I should wait? Are we talking like roughly 30 secs? 15 minutes? Couple of hours? And is the Firebase Console "View Source" functionality accurate? Like if the "View Source" shows the right thing, does that mean the deploy completed? Thank you again!

Comment: A minute or two at most.